# Deleted Products Still Showing in Search Bar

Tags: product, cache, search

We recently had to let our webdeveloper go and dont have a new hire yet. We are experiencing an issue with deleted products continuing to show up in our search bar. We've cleared caches and ensured the products are removed. No one here is knowledgeable enough to know what to do about this but its causing customer headaches so we need to resolve this. Can anyone give us a step by step on where to go and what to do to try to resolve this?

SOLVED! It was a doofinder issue. Thank you all for the help

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: Reindex the data it will get removed from the search bar.

Comment: we use magento 2.3.3

Comment: Ive reindex the data and its still showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Might be it cache related issue it will work after indexing the commands given below and check with hard refresh on the browser.

**php bin/magento index:reindex**
**php bin/magento cache:flush**

Comment: That didnt do anything unfortunately. We use Doo Finder so I'm working on getting the log in and hopefully that is whats causing the issue.